# Java android get content

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to get content,DOM, CSS...so the problem is when I call an url with parameters , it gives always the content of the initial page because that page call an ajax query and I want to get the last content after the ajax execution.

**This is my code :**

```
 public String getContent(String link){
    String content=null;
    try{

        //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36").timeout(10*1000).get();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        content =  doc.toString();
    }catch(IOException e){
        return "Invalid URL";
    }
    return content;
}
```

www.foo.com/page => initial Page

www.foo.com/page/aazere => Page with parameter

Help me please and thanks

Answer (score 0):

> […] because that page call an ajax query and I want to get the last content after the ajax execution.

**Ajax** execution ***isn't supported*** by Jsoup. But there's still a **solution** to this: Use a library (eg. HtmlUnit) to do the JS part and then parse the data with Jsoup.

#### For getting started:

- [Fetch contents(loaded through AJAX call) of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page/20642675#20642675)
- [How to completely read a site that contains javascript from an android service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691615/how-to-completely-read-a-site-that-contains-javascript-from-an-android-service/21705347#21705347)